# IBM Content Navigator custom step processor invalid security token

Tags: dojo, filenet-p8, ibm-content-navigator

We have a custom step processor deployed in ICN to open work items. When we open the workitems, it loads in custom step processor but we see a spinning circle and when debugged, below request was sent repeatedly

http://server:9083/navigator/jaxrs/getActions

The request header of this request has

```
security_token: undefined
```

and the response for this repeated action is

```
{}&&{"security_token":"-9150067219440232051","sessioninactivelimit":1800,"errors":[{"number":"1003","adminResponse":null,"moreInformation":null,"text":"Your session expired.","explanation":"Your session expired because of inactivity.","userResponse":"Log in again."}]}
```

Looks like the session is expired or when the step processor opens as a pop-up, session is not carried. But we are able to take actions like "Complete, close, cancel" on the step-processor window and it works fine but it's just that in the back-end, it keeps sending the request.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The  only way to get this working may be implement SSO for CNav user logins. Token based security will not work in CNav as IBM have removed that completely.

Comment: Thanks Krunal. But we did not establish session using security token. Opening workitem in a separate window is the OOTB feature of ICN. Also we don't have SSO enabled at this point.

Comment: Yes that functionality is OOTB but in the custom step processor did you  pass on the session identifier from the main window. The other actions which you mentioned are getting validated on the same session/window and not opening another one so it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

OK, this is what we did to get around the issue. It seems to be a bug/issue with the ICN version Version: 3.0.4 Build: icn304.001.294.

We created our own ContentViewer module by commenting out below line from the original ContentViewer.js

```
this.mainTabContainer.loadTabContextMenu()
```

Everything worked fine post this change. Fingers crossed as we are planning for a upgrade shortly.